# Routing messages in RabbitMQ topic exchange that do NOT match a pattern

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, mq, bunny

Two queues are bound to a topic exchange with the following routing keys:

Queue A, bound with routing key pattern match `*.foo`
Queue B, bound with routing key pattern match `*.bar`

I'd like to add a third queue to this exchange that receives messages that are neither `foo` messages nor `bar` messages. If I bind this queue with a `#` routing key, I naturally get all messages I need, but including `foo`'s and `bar`'s which I don't want.

Any way to route messages patching a pattern `NOT *.foo` AND `NOT *.bar` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to catch all messages that doesn't match any bindings, that can be done with [Alternate Exchange](http://www.rabbitmq.com/ae.html).

Add alternate exchange for existent one and collect all messages from that alternate exchanges:

```
standard workflow --> [main exchange (topic)]
                    |     --> via binding *.foo -->  [foo queue]
                    |     --> via binding *.bar -->  [bar queue]
                    v      
           [alternate exchange (let it be topic too)]
                    --> via binding * --> []
```

For more specific cases when you have N bindings but you want to catch all messages that doesn't match M bindings (where M < N) it is more problematic, but technically can be done via [Dead Letter Exchange](http://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html) and then publish it to custom exchange where you have only M bindings, and then apply case with Alternate Exchange. But it even sounds rusty, not even think about performance degradation (applied only if you have really high messages flow).

Comment: I recommend *not* using an AE because adding a new binding (ie. an observer with '#') will prevent the AE/fallback from working. This is something that can happen in real life and make things go sideways *really* fast with unexpected interactions.